# Creating a Filtered Data Extension from Account Record Type Filed in Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters

I need to segment audiences in Marketing Cloud based on the Account Record Type in Sales Cloud. With the Contact Object and Account Object the Account Record Type field is not available in Marketing Cloud and the majority of the synchronized fields are null/inconsistent to use for segmentation within the synchronized DE's in Marketing Cloud.

Is there a way or another workaround to create these audiences?

Comment: Can you check if you have selected the 'Account Record Type' field in your Account object setup, under the Data Sources [Contact builder]/

Comment: @VishalKumarCV I tried but the Account Record Type does not show up as a field in the Object synchronization only Record Type ID which is not used on the contact object but on the account object.